# looping through json in perl

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to grab some information out of a json export from Ping.  My rusty Perl skills are failing me as I'm getting lost in the weeds with the dereferencing.  Rather than bang my head against the wall some more I thought I'd post a question since all the google searches are leading here.

My understanding is that `decode_json` converts items into an array of hashes and each hash has strings and some other arrays of hashes as contents.  This seems to bear out when attempting to get to an individual string value but only if I manually specify a specific array element. I can't figure out how to loop through the items.

The JSON comes back like this:

```
{
  "items":[
     {
       #lots of values here are some examples
       "type": "SP",
       "contactInfo": {
          "company": "Acme",
          "email": "john.doe@acme.com"
     }
 ]
}
```

I had no problems getting to actual values

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;


my $json;
{
  local $/; #Enable 'slurp' mode
  open my $fh, "<", "idp.json";
  $json = <$fh>;
  close $fh;
}

my $data = decode_json($json);

#array print $data->{'items'};
#hash print $data->{'items'}->[0];
#print $data->{'items'}->[0]->{'type'};
```

But, I can't figure out how to iterate through the array of items.  I've tried `for` and `foreach` and various combinations of dereferencing, and it keeps telling me that the value I'm looping thru is still an array.  If `$data->{'items'}` is an array, then presumably I should be able to do some variation of

```
foreach my $item ($data->{'items'})
```

or

```
my @items = $data->{'items'};

for (@items)
{
  # stuff
}
```

But, I keep getting arrays back and I have to add in the ->[0] to get to a specific value.

Comment: Keep in mind that Perl data structures and JSON are nearly identical. It's very portable from one to another.

Answer (score 4):

`$data->{'items'}` is a reference to an array (of hash references).  You need to dereference it, with `@{ }`:

```
use JSON;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $json;
{
  local $/; #Enable 'slurp' mode
  $json = <DATA>;
}

my $data = decode_json($json);
for my $item (@{ $data->{items} }) {
    print "$item->{type}\n";
}

__DATA__
{
  "items":[
     {
       "type": "SP",
       "contactInfo": {
          "company": "Acme",
          "email": "john.doe@acme.com"
        }
     }
 ]
}
```

Output:

```
SP
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it had to be something super obvious but for some reason I was thinking when I printed it out it'd say ARRAYREF if it was a reference instead of ARRAY.   No idea why I was thinking that.